# stuck with encodings in python with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, beautifulsoup

The page is encoded in UTF-8 and with python's HTMLParser it works well, no `UnicodeDecodeError`, but I do get an error when I try to parse it with BeautifulSoup.
I've tried `_*_` coding: `utf-8 _*_`, `.encode('utf-8')` everywhere and am still getting the error

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
args=urllib.urlencode({'keywords':'magic'})
doc=urllib.urlopen('http://www.example.com/submit', args)
soup=BeautifulSoup(doc)
stuff = soup.findAll('section',id='banner')
print stuff

Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
        print stuff
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xed' in position 112: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok i found the solution in my last try, maybe it will help others with the same problem.
It needs to be encoded, not decoded

```
print( [e.encode('utf-8', 'ignore') for e in stuff] )
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be getting `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii'..` errors when you print. This is often caused if your `locale` is corrupt or set to `C`. Python is then unable to set an appropriate encoder on the stdout stream.

Run `locale` and check for errors or warnings.

If you can't fix your locale, you can often override Python's stdout encoder with by setting `PYTHONIOENCODING` in your environment to an encoding that matches your terminal emulation. Often you can get by with:

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
```

or

```
PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 python my_script.py
```